# Problem with paging when using query string in codeigniter

Tags: string, codeigniter

i am using query string to search in codeigniter.
my url is like

http:// localhost/testing/main?serch=res

but my paging is like

http: //localhost/testing/main/10

now i want to attach "?serch=res" with paging

http: //localhost/testing/main/10?serch=res

how can i attach please help

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use segments you could format your url like so:

http: //localhost/testing/main/res/10

then to access your serch and pagination parameters it would be:

```
$serch = $this->uri->segment(2);
$per_page = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html